# How rewrite all JS, CSS, IMG to static subdomain?

Tags: javascript, css, image, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have:

```
sub.domain.com/js/test.js
sub.domain.com/image1.jpg
sub.domain.com/test.css
```

How rewrite all the file types to:

```
static-sub.domain.com/....
```

?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Something akin to what's below should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sub\.domain\.com/(js/*\.js)$ static-sub.domain.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^sub\.domain\.com/(*\.jpg)$ static-sub.domain.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^sub\.domain\.com/(*\.css)$ static-sub.domain.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

You'll likely need to tweak it to your specific scenario. Notice the usage of capturing groups (`(js/*\.js)`) to store the variable path information to be used in the destination (`$1`). Also note the `NC`, `R` and `L` options; which stand for "no casing" (case insensetive), "redirect" (redirect the request) and "last rule" (stop processing further rules if this rule is a match).